NestJS: Log API cal into a file in S3
I have a NestJS backend to a mobile app. I want to log the details of each API call into a file in S3. I need this to be done asynchronously in background to not slow down the API and also handle overwrites. The write to each API call will happen in parts as follows:

Write with endpoint, requestHeader, requestBody
Write with statusCode, responseBody, responseHeader
Write the error trace if present

I have used the middleware for this as follows. But I need help with the actual method appendLogToS3 implementation. How do I do this?
import {
    Injectable,
    NestMiddleware,
    UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { FirebaseService } from '../firebase/firebase.service';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import onFinished from 'on-finished';
import { AwsService } from '../aws/aws.service';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'; // Importing uuid package

@Injectable()
export class UserMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    private user_id: number;
    private incrementingId = 1;

    constructor(
        private firebase: FirebaseService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private config: ConfigService,
        private awsService: AwsService,
    ) {}

    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        if (!['/heartbeat'].includes(req.originalUrl)) {
            let device = String(req.headers['x-device-os']);
            if (device === undefined) {
                device = 'web';
            }
            const apiCallId = uuidv4()

            // Capture the response details for post-controller logging
            let responseBody = '';
            let status_code = 0;
            const originalSend = res.send.bind(res);
            const originalStatus = res.status.bind(res);

            res.status = (statusCode: number) => {
                status_code = statusCode;
                return originalStatus(statusCode);
            };

            res.send = (body: any) => {
                try {
                    responseBody = typeof body === 'string' ? JSON.parse(body) : body;
                } catch (e) {
                    responseBody = body;
                }
                return originalSend(body);
            };

            // Listen for when the response is finished
            onFinished(res, async (err) => {

                // Append the final log to the same file in S3 after the response is completed
                await this.appendLogToS3({
                    status_code: status_code,
                    response: responseBody,
                    responseHeaders: res.getHeaders()
                }, apiCallId);
            });

            // Check for JWT authorization and validate token
            if (!req.user && req.headers.authorization) {
                const jwtToken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
                let token = null;
                let firebaseData = null;
                let newToken = null;

                try {
                    const decodedToken: any = jwt.verify(
                        jwtToken,
                        this.config.get('JWT_SECRET'),
                    );
                    this.user_id = decodedToken.sub;
                    token = decodedToken.data.token;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid token');
                }

                try {
                    firebaseData = await this.firebase.verifyToken(token, true);
                } catch (err) {
                    if (err.code && err.code === 'auth/id-token-expired') {
                        const user = await this.userService.fetchUser({
                            id: this.user_id,
                        });
                        const response: false | AxiosResponse =
                            await this.firebase.refreshToken(
                                user.refresh_token,
                            );
                        if (response && response.data) {
                            newToken = await this.userService.signToken(
                                user.id,
                                response.data.id_token,
                            );
                        } else {
                            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid token');
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid token');
                    }
                }

                if (firebaseData) {
                    const user = await this.userService.fetchUser({
                        firebaseId: firebaseData.id,
                    });
                    req.user = {
                        data: user,
                        token: newToken,
                    };
                    this.user_id = user.id;
                }
            }
            await this.appendLogToS3({
                id: apiCallId,
                endpoint: req.originalUrl,
                requestHeader: req.headers,
                request: req.body,
                user: this.user_id
            }, apiCallId);
        }

        next();
    }
}

